# Using a c++ builder application with an external dll

Tags: c++, qt, dll

I'm trying to use an `external dll` in my c++ builder application. The dll (let.s call it X.dll) was created with Qt Creator (using MingW 32 bit compiler, tried gcc as well )
and consists of a single functon to keep things simple (besides X.dll, an import library X.a is also created).

The dll header (Dll_lib.h) is basically just

```
__declspec(dllexport)  Dll_method(float *p, int n);
```

If I create a simple Qt application, add the dll header to it and link it to the dll import library X.a, everythink works as expected.

However, when I try to use the dll in my c++ builder application, I get an "***unresolved external _Dll_method referenced from ...***" error.

The part of my c++ builder app that references the dll looks like

```
#include "lib\Dll_lib.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "X.lib")

__declspec(dllimport)  Dll_method(float *p, int n);

.....
```

X.lib was created directly from the dll using the implib tool that comes bundled with c++ builder.  I also tried to create X.lib from X.a using coff2omf tool but nothing worked and I always get the same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ environments have a habit of name mangling to support overloads, different arguments with the same name, like:

```
int use(int x, char y); // mangles to something like use__Int__Chr.
int use(double x);      // mangles to something like use__Dbl.
```

This allows the *correct* one to be linked depending on the arguments.

You may need to wrap it inside `extern "C"` to get it to not mangle the name, something like:

```
extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllimport)  Dll_method(float *p, int n);
}
```

That's assuming you're creating it without name mangling and using it from something that assumes it *is* mangled. If it's mangled on *both* sides, you'll probably have to create *and* use it with `extern "C"` since there's no guarantee different compilers will mangle with the *same* rules.

---

As an aside, you should be able to examine the object files or DLLs created by your toolchain, to ascertain what the function is called where it's defined and also what it's expected to be by the caller. Under Linux, I'd use something like `nm`, I'm not sure what the equivalent is for Windows.

Comment: I've already tried that , same error but thanks anyway.

Comment: @dsp_user: are you compiling *both* sides with mangling? As per the update, there's no mandate that different environments use the *same* rules for mangling. It's probably best to turn it off both where you create the function and where you call it.

Comment: I've tried not to use name mangling on both sides (extern C on both sides ). Let me see if I can find out what's exactly written in the import library.

Comment: Yup, it was name mangling. I wrongly thought I placed extern c on both ends.